# Every change made by "Author" role is going to "pending review"

Tags: pages, user-roles, review

I don't know if this is an issue with the module https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/, or this is an internal behavior of WordPress, but for some reason, every time a user with "Author" role makes an update in some page content, this page goes to "pending review" and I have (as Admin), to approve it.

How can I avoid this and let "Author" have its changes auto-approved?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: Within the  https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/ module, just **check** the option "Publish Posts" for the "Author" role...